# How to validate related objects request data from a parent controller in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I'm using Laravel 8.x and have a one-to-one and one-to-many relationship with models as follows.

```
class ServiceProvider extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $guarded = [];

    public function contact() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Contact');
    }

    public function services() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Service');
    }
}
```

I'm using a single form to get all the data. The problem is both `Contact` and `Service` has their own validation to be done. I can duplicate the validation in the `ServiceProviderController`. But it seems ugly and violate DRY. Is there a way to call the `ContactController` and `ServiceController` to do the validation and return the validation result to be accessed by the `ServiceProviderController`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I guess you are doing something like:

```
   /**
     * Store a new service provider.
     *
     * @param  Request  $request
     * @return Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
            'body' => 'required',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect('services/create')
                        ->withErrors($validator)
                        ->withInput();
        }

        // Store The Service Provider...
    }
```

If Yes, I would recommend using a form request validator to validate the request. So if the request is get passed your controller will be called. Also, you can use the same Request Validation rule for both controllers. you can read how to create and use one more [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#creating-form-requests).

Answer (score 0):

You can set up enumerator classes that will return validation rules for you, or even declare static properties on your model which will hold an array of validation rules, and which can be called like: `ServiceProvider::$rules` or something similar.

This way you will keep all your rules at one place. You can't explicitly call controllers whenever, they respond to routes.

When you get the validation rules, just `use $request->validate()` method and send the rules you gathered to it.